# Как настроить плагин Emmet в VS Code, чтобы теги html закрывались как в SublimeText?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, sublime-text, emmet

Как сделать также, чтобы при выборе из выпадающего окна тег закрывался, а курсор был в середине? Пример на картинке

[image: мои плагины 2]
[image: мои плагины]

[image: пример]

Comment: насколько я знаю, Emmet уже встроен в VS Code

Comment: Offtop: Я думаю вам стоит удалить `Rainbow bracket` т.к. в VSCode есть данная функция, которая работает куда быстрее. А так же `auto rename tag`.

Comment: Насчет вопроса, вам нужно писать название тега без начинающей `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Без всяких расширений и дополнительных настроек, все работает так как вам нужно из коробки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]